# Malicious httpd log entry

Tags: attacks, apache

Besides some other hacking attempts, I am seeing the following kind of log entries in my Apache logs which I cannot fully understand.

`5.188.x.x - - [10/Feb/2023:14:40:14 +0100] "GET http://5.188.x.x/echo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 2691 "https://www.google.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/70.0.3538.77 Safari/537.36"`

What does it mean when there is another http request url (here `GET http://5.188.x.x/echo.php`) instead of a regular resource (e.g. `GET /home`)? Is it in a way an outgoing request? Especially as it returns 200.

Is it something to worry about?

Comment: Basically, the attacker is trying to abuse the Reverse proxy, if your reverse proxy is lacking or has improper proxy rules, it might lead to access into the private network access.

For instance, if you use any cloud provider with a metadata service, the attacker might get access to the metadata.